# Python (flask/ marshmallow)ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, flask, marshmallow

I am working on a Flask project and I am using marshmallow to validate user input.
Below is a code snippet:

```
def create_user():
    in_data = request.get_json()
    data, errors = Userschema.load(in_data)
    if errors:
        return (errors), 400
    fname = data.get('fname')
    lname = data.get('lname')
    email = data.get('email')
    password = data.get('password')
    cpass = data.get('cpass')
```

When I eliminate the `errors` part, the code works perfectly. When I run it as it is, I get the following error:

> builtins.ValueError
>
> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last)
>
> File
>   "/home/..project-details.../venv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py",
>   line 2000, in **call**
>
> error = None
>
> ctx.auto_pop(error)

```
def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
    """Shortcut for :attr:`wsgi_app`."""
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)


def __repr__(self):
    return '<%s %r>' % (
        self.__class__.__name__,
        self.name,
```

Note: The var `in_data` is a dict.
Any ideas??

Comment: Have you tried `return (errors, 400)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend you check your dependency versions.
Per the [Marshmallow API reference](http://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html#schema), schema.load returns:

> Changed in version 3.0.0b7: This method returns the deserialized data rather than a (data, errors) duple. A ValidationError is raised if invalid data are passed.

I suspect python is trying to unpack the dict (returned as a singular object) into two variables. The exception is raised because there is nothing to pack into the 'errors' variable. The below reproduces the error:

```
d = dict()
d['test'] = 10101
a, b = d
print("%s : %s" % (a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

according to the documentation in its most recent version (3.17.1) the way of handling with validation errors is as follows:

```
from marshmallow import ValidationError

try:
    result = UserSchema().load({"name": "John", "email": "foo"})
except ValidationError as err:
    print(err.messages)  # => {"email": ['"foo" is not a valid email address.']}
    print(err.valid_data)  # => {"name": "John"}
```