# How do I read the parameter of the GET request in a RESTful Flask/SQLAlchemy/Marshmallow environment

Tags: python-3.x, rest, get, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I was working my way through a couple of tutorials before xmas and I'm now trying to pick up where I left of.
Trying to teach myself REST by building some simple API end points. My confusion is coming from the fact that I cant find the tutorials I was using and there seems to be several different ways to solve the problem. So now I'm not sure what is the correct way to do it.
The code is working for returning all customers in the DB, now I want to return a specific customer based on their Id

Ok this is what I have...

I have an app.py that defines the resource like this:

```
api.add_resource(CustomerResource, '/Customer')
```

I have a models.py that defines the customer class like this:

```
ma = Marshmallow()
db = SQLAlchemy()

class Customer(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'customers'
    __table_args__ = {"schema":"business"}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    status = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

class CustomerSchema(ma.Schema):
    id = fields.Integer()
    name = fields.String(required=True)
    status = fields.Integer(required=True)
```

I have customer.py that defines the customer class as this:

```
customers_schema = CustomerSchema(many=True)
customer_schema = CustomerSchema()

class CustomerResource(Resource):
    def get(self):
        customers = Customer.query.all()
        customers = customers_schema.dump(customers)
        return {'status': 'success', 'data': customers}, 200
```

I have tried using request.args, but I dont believe that is the correct way to go due to the fact it will become unspported.

So the above all works with the GET successfully returning all customers. But now I want to be able to use GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/Customer/10 and to just return the details for customer id = 10

I'm not sure whether I need to define a new resource or whether the existing CustomerResource can be modified to test for the presence of a parameter.

Any guidance appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you're correct don't use the `request.args` method, rather **create another resource**. Remember `api.add_resource` is essentially just **mapping a handler to a RESTFUL endpoint**. If you had a lot of *duplicate business logic code* shared between endpoints I would suggest that you *abstract out that business logic into a helper function* and *utilize this helper function within your resource definitions,* but in this particular case this isn't necessary. I would consider doing the following:

**app.py:**

```
api.add_resource(CustomerList, '/Customer')
api.add_resource(Customer, '/Customer/<int:id>')
```

**I would rename customer.py to something like routes.py and it would contain the following:**

```
class CustomerList(Resource):
    def get(self):
        customers = Customer.query.all()
        customers = customers_schema.dump(customers)
        return {'status': 'success', 'data': customers}, 200

class Customer(Resource):
    def get(self, id):
        customer = Customer.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
        customer, errors = customers_schema.dump(customer)
        if errors:
           return jsonify(errors), 422
        return customer, 200
```

Keep your **models.py** file as is, and I would consider utilizing the `jsonify` method that flask provides for returning your data within your RESTFUL endpoints. I have shown an example of this in the specific customer endpoint.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thank you Nathan. I have made the changes that you suggested. The request for all customers still works. The request for a specific customer results in an TypeError: 'Customer' object is not iterable error for the line "customer = Customer.query.filter_by(id=id).first()". Any idea why?

Comment: Hi, it may be a casting error since your Customer table's primary key is an Integer try changing your customer specific resource to the following: api.add_resource(Customer, '/Customer/<int:id>' and let me know if that resolves the issue. If not I can take a look at your code if you provide me a link to it :)

Comment: Thank you, Nathan. The not iterable error was my mistake and I have corrected it. I do have another problem though in the line you suggested **customer, errors = customers_schema.dump(customer)** it causes the following error **ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)** I have edited the original post to show where the schema is declared. But I'm afraid I dont really understand this part at all - it came from the tutorial

Comment: Ok no worries, I will look at it in a bit

Comment: OK answering my previous comment. The issue is that the version of Marshmallow I am using no longer returns data, errors - it simply returns the de-serialised data. As per this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51817237/python-flask-marshmallowvalueerror-too-many-values-to-unpack-expected-2)

Comment: Last question.. what would I need to change in order to support urls in the form of /api/Customer/?id=1

Comment: I am glad you got it working! Flask-Restful has a request parsing module, called **reqparse**: https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.6/reqparse.html **but it's being depreciated** so I would checkout **WebArgs** for this functionality if it's needed: https://github.com/marshmallow-code/webargs/blob/dev/examples/flaskrestful_example.py I linked the flask-restful example from their documentation. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Once again thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for!